# Display glitches in certain apps

Tags: xiaomi, bugs

Device specs
[image]

I have so far only noticed this problem in Quora app, and Chrome (some pages). But these are the apps I almost always browse the net with. I did not notice any such issue offline.  It has been around three days.

[image]

These are just a few examples of the types of glitches that occur.

I have tried:
-uninstalling Google's WebView after hearing of a recent update causing trouble
-forcing GPU rendering.
-Reinstalling Chrome and Quora.

Just in case this helps: I had observed text glitches on Chrome for quite some time before this started. Usually, one or a few words would be disfigured. Changing zoom would correct it. Also, today many files of mine have disappeared. They aren't hidden, just nowhere to be seen.

Oh yeah and

[image]

Comment: Do you encounter the same problems with the pre-installed manufacturer browser?

Comment: @MorrisonChang apparently not.

Comment: I would also check in Firefox as they use a different render engine. If rebooting the phone doesn't clear the problem up in Chrome, it could be Chrome graphics driver issue or hardware fault. You may want to file a bug report: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1

Comment: @MorrisonChang I forgot to mention that I rebooted

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was disabling "GPU rasterization" in chrome://flags